# Korteweg-de Vries equation: Term has evaporated

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, integrable-systems

In the [original paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/14786449508620739) of Korteweg and de Vries, they derive the equation
$$
\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial t} = \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}} \partial_{x}(\eta^2/2 + 2\alpha \eta/3  + \sigma \partial_x^2 \eta/3)
$$
where "$\alpha$ is a small but arbitrary constant, which is in close connexion with the exact velocity of the uniform motion given to the liquid".

However, in later works, it appears that $\alpha$ has either been [set to zero](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.15.240), or set to [one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Korteweg-deVriesEquation.html).

Is this constant not super meaningful? Why can it be disregarded, or set to one?

Comment: the original language implies that small is typically non-arbitrary?  the set of all small constants does include zero ... one could argue that there are few things less arbitrary than zero ... does arbitrary have a mathematical definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after you non-dimensionalize away as many constants as you can, absorbing them into the normalizations of *x* and *t*, you note
your remainder equation is mostly linear except in one term,  which I isolate in the second term, together with the linear object of your puzzlement,
$$
(\partial_t +\partial_x^3)\eta + \sigma \partial_x \Bigl (\eta^2/2 + 2\alpha \eta/3 \Bigr ) =0,
$$
where different authors chose the freedom of this non-dimensionalization to tweak the respective constants in all kinds of ways... experiment with these options yourself.

Here, you are meant to observe that the $\alpha$ component in the second term is phony, since you may complete the square in   the second term,
$$
\partial_x \Bigl  ( (\eta +2\alpha/3)^2 - 4\alpha^2/9\Bigr ) = \partial_x (\eta +2\alpha/3)^2 ,
$$
so redefining $u=\eta+2\alpha/3$ completely eliminates it from the problem: it is a phantom parameter,
$$
u_t+u_{xxx} + \sigma u u_x=0 . 
$$